# Ask one property of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In my textbook it says, if $\varphi_\xi(\lambda_0) = e^{2\pi i \alpha }$ for some $\lambda_0 \neq 0$ and some real $\alpha$, then $\xi$ takes at most a countable number of values. The values of $\xi$ are of the form $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0} (\alpha +m)$, where m is an integer.

I know the proof. But I don't know the takeway of this property. It seems that $e^{2\pi i \alpha }$ is located on the unit circle. And since  $\xi$ takes at most a countable number of values, $\xi$ thus is a discrete random variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume $\lambda_0>0$. Then form some $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$,
\begin{align}
1=e^{-i\theta}\widehat{\mu}(\lambda_0)=\int \cos(x\lambda_0-\theta)\,\mu(dx)
\end{align}
It follows that $x\mapsto\cos(x\lambda_0-\theta)=1$ $\mu$--a.s.  Hence, $\operatorname{supp}\mu\subset \frac{\theta}{\lambda_0}+\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0}\mathbb{Z}$.

Here we use the fact that if $f\geq0$ and $\int f\,d\mu=0$, then $f=0$ $\mu$-almost surely,

Comment: What can we learn from this property?

Comment: That only probability measures on a lattice (or translation of a lattice on areal line) have characteristic functions taking values on the unit circle (besides at time $t=0$)